# Problem of links when create friendly links with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, directory

When I use this code which make a friendly ULRs:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?ps=$1 [NC,L]
```

all work just fine.

but when I try to add a "category name" to the URL like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?pc=$1ps=$2 [NC,L]
```

It's work fine actually but the problem I had is on the website which all links become start with (the category's directory), its suppose to be like this: http://localhost/mysite/title.html
but they look like this: http://localhost/mysite/category/title.html

I mean links in source code not in the bar Address, including css and images Source links. which lead to an disaster on the style and nonfunctional links.

Comment: well it seems that I didn't look enough before ask my question.
the question you did provide for me is the solution for what I ask for, sorry for duplication